# I can't change my Google+ profile name

Tags: google-plus

So I really want to change my Google Plus name, but it's telling me that I've changed it too recently. I know that the current name policy is a maximum of 3 changes per 90 days, (or 3 months) and I know for sure that I haven't changed it at all in a long time, more than 90 days, so I can't imagine any reason why it would be telling me this. The only thing that may be setting this off, is that I accidentally pressed "edit my name" and pressed save just a few minutes ago, but I didn't make any changes at all. I honestly don't think that would affect it though. Is there any way around this? I really want to change my name, please help.